# I cannot download spring-data-gemfire in Maven. What are corrects repository/group/artifact ?

Tags: maven, gemfire

I cannot download   spring-data-gemfire in Maven.  What are corrects   repository/group/artifact   ?

pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-gemfire</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
<dependency>    

<repository>
            <id>spring.io</id>
            <name>spring.io</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
            <id>mvnrepository</id>
            <name>mvnrepository</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
            <id>apache.nexus</id>
            <name>ASF Nexus Staging</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
            <id>springsource-repo</id>
            <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
</repository>
```

-- the error  in compile maven --
Could not resolve dependencies
Failed read artifact descriptor for com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:jar:8.2.3
 Could not transfer artifact com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:pom:8.2.3 from/to spring.io (http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/): null to http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/gemstone/gemfire/gemfire/8.2.3/gemfire-8.2.3.pom: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 1]

Comment: The entry mvnrepository.com ...is simply wrong...The repository.apache.org/content/groups/stagings is also wrong...and furthermore the exception: `UnresolvedAddressException`...looks like you have some kind of proxy/firewall issue or something else...

Comment: If I navigate in browser the url http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/gemstone/gemfire/gemfire/8.2.3/gemfire-8.2.3.pom    is OK !!!